# FTP Upload files whose names & locations are contained in text file

Tags: linux, command-line, ftp

I have a text file with filenames and their paths, e.g.

**list.txt**

```
/dirA/fileA.bin
/dirB/fileC.txt
/dirB/fileD.txt
(...and so on)
```

How can I upload these files via ftp to a destination that already has the tree structure which matches the sources, e.g. source `/dirA/fileA.bin` to go in destination `/dirA/fileA.bin`, and so on.

The closest I found is the following after searching, but it's not quite it.

```
curl -T "{/dirA/fileA.bin}" ftp://XXX/dirA --user abc:xyz
```

Any help would appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't have access to any ftp server these days. But I came across a page which might work: https://kb.iu.edu/d/afqg  . Basically, you can put all the commands in a shell script. You can write a little script to convert list.txt into `put /dirA/fileA.bin /dirA/fileA.bin` and run it.

Comment: What do you mean it's not quite it?

Comment: @Seth Yes, sorry about that. It is often used to express that one is not certain about something. [More info](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+quite). Or [perhaps this](https://english.stackexchange.com/) too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but not very helpful. Instead explain what works or doesn't work about the command in your case. [curl man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/curl) see -T.

Answer (score 0):

Some bash script would work for you. But why do you want FTP? If you can use SSH it's easier... Something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
input="/path/to/txt/file"
spawn ssh user@remotecomputer
expect "password:"
sleep 1
send "<your password>\r"

while IFS= read -r line
do
    rsync -v -e ssh $line user@remotecomputer:/remotepath
done < "$input"
```

If you export your public key to the remote machine, you can even pass without the initial connection and rsync works over ftp. It's basically the same...

Comment: I understand that and thanks for this script. However it's for an ancient computer on my private LAN that has a barebones Windows based FTP server, and I don't want to fiddle with it too much! :D

Comment: Than replace rsync with csync.